# C# setting length of main string as length of a substring

Tags: c#

I have problem with the `.length` code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Str_Basics = "AIKdepNCZSIDETe";
        int Long_Str_Bas;
        string Sub_Str_1;
        string Sub_Str_2;
        Long_Str_Bas = Str_Basics.Length;

        //Provide value for M
        int M = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Provide value for M");
        M = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < Long_Str_Bas; i++) ;

        // First substring
        Sub_Str_1 = Str_Basics.Substring(1, (M - 1));

        // Second substring
        Sub_Str_2 = Str_Basics.Substring((M + 1),Long_Str_Bas);
        Console.WriteLine("Substring is " + Sub_Str_1);
        Console.WriteLine("Substring is " + Sub_Str_2);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I do not know how to transfer `Str_Basics.Length` into a cordinates of `Sub_Str_2` if anyone could explain me how does the `.Length` works I would be really thankful.

Comment: It's really unclear to me what you're trying to achieve. `.Length` is just a read-only property returning the length of a string. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to split a string at the position given by the user at position M. But what you are asking doesn't look like anything that is resembled in code. So more detailed explanation is needed. Also, your for-loop does nothing as it is written.

Comment: From your code, it seems you want to know how work the `length`parameter of method `Substring(int startIndex, int length);` instead of property `Length` of the `string` class, is this correct?

Comment: Sorry was actually writing in a hurry. Yes, I wanted to know if I can conver lenght parameter into number which defines the lenght of another string. I think I fixed it by changing this line Sub_Str_2 = Str_Basics.Substring((M+1),(A-(M+1)));

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to do this:

```
    // First substring
    Sub_Str_1 = Str_Basics.Substring(0, M);

    // Second substring
    Sub_Str_2 = Str_Basics.Substring(M);
```